seeking a command line smalltalk. is gst-smalltalk no longer maintained?
Is it wise to use gst-smalltalk for  scripting? It used to be my favorite lean-mean smalltalk but now I have doubts.
e.g. brew install gst-smalltalk gets me GST 3.2.5.  that version has unresolved bugs. Such as
(Behavior evaluate: '1.2')

crashes but this does not:
(Behavior evaluate: '1.2e0')

As of eleven years ago, this was a known bug that required recompiling with the -no-pie option
floating point raises divide by zero error in GNU smalltalk (gst)
So avoid gst-smalltalk? In favor of what? (ideally something else I can use for scripting without the overhead of a standard ST GUI environment).
